# One icon wider on your profile

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed, design

On the profile page, there is a list with the user's informations :

- location
- links
- views
- last seen
- ...

Here is the information on my profile

[image: User's information]

All those items have an icon with a size of `18x18` **except one icon**.

Once you've seen it, you can't unsee it...

---

The "*member for*" icon has a width of `20px` instead of `18px` thus the text is moved to the right compared to other texts.

Why is it like this ? Can't you use `18x18` size everywhere ?

Comment: +1 for the pure unadulterated pedantry

Comment: Especially when it's an SVG that will scale easily :)

Comment: @DavidG Thanks. I saw it few minutes ago and now I cannot think about something else

Comment: @DavidG Thanks for making me learn 2 new English words: unadulterated - pedantry

Comment: I don’t know about pedantry… this definitely bothered me instantly. It doesn’t have to be the same width, just aligned.

Comment: @Ryan True, but aligning them is a lot more work than changing `20` to `18` :)

Comment: And the location icon is left-aligned instead of centered like the rest!

Comment: _Somone's_ been hanging around with the QA folks again!

Comment: It's 19 x 18 for me. Not as noticeable.

Comment: Is this the right place to complain about [the vote/edit/flag statistics icons' silent change from grey to black](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAOkw.png)?

Comment: @DavidG but -1 for the lack of a free-hand circle

Comment: Why did you have to point this out!? Now every time I go to a profile page, I can't unsee it!

Comment: Plot twist - all the other icons are actually meant to be 20px wide.

Comment: If these icons are common for all SE sites, is this post need to migrate to MSE?

Comment: @JornVernee I think it was just changed to 19, pretty sure it was 20 before this post!

Comment: It is now `19px` but still only for this icon

Comment: But it also now has a left margin of -1.

Comment: This is relevant: https://xkcd.com/1015/

Answer (score 3):

So, with the 1px change down to 19px, the text is fully aligned:

[image: look ma!, aligned text!]